# Within Xcode, Is 'pod install' Executed by One Person or Will Each Person Executing the App Need to Install

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am one of 5 working on a project testing through Xcode. We each test a version of the app on our own machines. I've installed some [Firebase products](https://firebase.google.com/products/) (Crashlytics and Performance Monitoring) that required me to `$ pod install`. Will everyone in my group need to `$ pod install` individually as well after they pull my latest commit from GitHub. Or do they not need to do anything since I've already installed the pod on my end prior to pushing to GitHub?

Comment: I mean, if they have to install Xcode they should be capable of executing `pod install`. Don't you want the others to have to install cocoapods or do you just want to make it more convenient for them?

Comment: @lufritz we all are running Xcode on our individual machines and have been pushing the app for testing onto our individual phones for a week now. Since I just added some Firebase products to the existing pod and performed `$ pod install` on my end before committing to GitHub, will everyone else need to `$ pod install` in order for the Firebase products to work on their end after pulling my commit?

Comment: If you didn't put something to `.gitignore` it should work

Comment: It depends on whether you add the downloaded pod code to your repository.  Some people do, some don't.   Personally, I don't, so each person needs to run `pod install` to install/update the pods after they pull the repo.  Other people do add the pods to the repo, so you simply need to checkout, although someone still needs to take responsibility to periodically check for new pod updates

Comment: @lufritz based on what you're saying since it is not part of `.gitignore` it should start working for everyone immediately in my group once they pull my commit based on my initial `$ pod install`.

Comment: Yes, it should work

Comment: You should not be putting things into source control that can easily be recreated.

Comment: @rmaddy meaning, is it best practice to add my `Pods` folder to `.gitignore`?

Comment: I would. Anything actually generated by `pod install` really shouldn't be kept in source control.